# What is the use of // operator in Python and when is it advisable?

Tags: python-2.7

How is it different than "`/`"?
I tried `print 10//5` and `print 10/5` and both gave the same result.

Comment: `//` is integer division

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print 10.0/6
print 10.0//6
```

The first is regular division, which results in a floating-point number, whereas the latter is integer division, which truncates the decimal part.

Comment: o/p is 1 for both.

Comment: Make it 10.0. Also @synchronizer, this is not an answer

Comment: I was trying not too give absolutely everything away but yes, I see your point. Sorry about that.